# Unify different separators in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df with ~450000 rows and 4 columns like "HK" as in the example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "HK": [
            "19000000-ac-;ghj-;qrs",
            "19000000- abcd-",
            "19000000 -abc;klm-",
            "19000000 - abc-;",
            "19000000 a-",
        ]
    }
)
df.head()

| HK
| -------------
| 19000000-ac-;ghj-;qrs
| 19000000- abcd-
| 19000000 -abc-;klm-
| 19000000 - abc-;
| 19000000 a-
```

I always have 8 digits followed by a value. The digits and the value are separated through different forms of "-" (no whitespace inbetween digits and value, whitespace left, whitespace right, whitespace left and right or only a whitespace without a "-").

I would like to get a unified presentation whith "$digits$ - $value$" so that my column looks like this:

```
| HK
| -------------
| 19000000 - ac-;ghj-;qrs
| 19000000 - abcd-
| 19000000 - abc-;klm-
| 19000000 - abc-;
| 19000000 - a-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`pd.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with a regular expression:

```
>>> df['HK'].str.replace(r'(?<=\d{8})[\s-]+(?=\w)', ' - ', regex=True)
 
0    19000000 - ac-;ghj-;qrs
1           19000000 - abcd-
2        19000000 - abc;klm-
3           19000000 - abc-;
4              19000000 - a-
Name: HK, dtype: object
```

Explaining the regular expression. There is a lookback `(?<=\d{8})` requiring that there are eight digits immediately before the main section. The main section is `[\s-]+` which requires one or more characters which are whitespace or hyphens. Then there is a lookahead `(?=\w)` requiring that immediately after this is a word character (in this case, something like `a`).